# Display node information in block

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can I create a custom block snippet (or download an available module) that would display a selected amount of information about a node in Drupal (6)? (i.e. author, creation date and published status)

I would later make this node available to `admin` user and only in certain `content types`, as a mean of seeing node information *in-situ* while browsing the web only as admin (this part I know how to achieve).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom block (`admin/build/block/add`)

Make sure `PHP Filter` module is enabled already

For your block body select input filter as `PHP Code`

Add these lines in the body to load node information

```
<?php
    if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))){
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
        $user = user_load(array('uid' => $node->uid));
        print "Author: " . l($user->name, 'user/' . $node->uid);
        print "Creation date: " . date('m/d/y h:i:s', $node->created);
        print "Publish Status: " . ($node->status) ? "Published" : "Unpublished";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Would this work with nodes that have different URL than `node/nid`? I am using pretty URLs.

Comment: it will not effect if you use pretty url or auto path modules. Means that if your node is appearing with some custom alias then arg(0) will always output as 'node' and arg(1) as node id

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `Views` & `Context` modules.

You can use a block display in `Views` to output the desired fields. Add an argument, then select the option to get the argument from the url.

`Context` module allows you to (among other things) set access rules based on roles.

I use both of these modules in all of my Drupal installs and find them quite helpful.

http://drupal.org/project/views

http://drupal.org/project/context

Answer (score 0):

Views are totally advisable, writing custom code for something like that is a bad practice... In general the combination CCK & views is very poweerful in Drupal!